# I get the wrong image size after applying the size calculation formula

Tags: image, size, png

I am trying to calculate the size of image in K bytes based on the image width and height in pixel and the bit depth and check it with its size.
I have applied 2 formulas:

1. (width * height * bit depth ) / (8 * 1024 )
2. (width * height * 8 ) / 1024

but every time I got a size result different from the on showed in the image properties window.
For example:

[image: first example]

When applying the formulas I got a size different and way bigger than 467 Kb.

I am wondering if I am using the wrong formula.
How can I get the same image size based on width, height and bit depth?

Comment: You do know that PNG are compressed right?

Comment: I am actually newbie and I don't have so much experience in this domain. if the image is compressed, how can I then include that in my calculation?

Comment: You can't. The compression ratio depends on the actual image content. I just fiddle with https://www.faststone.org/FSViewerDetail.htm and the formula holds if I turn off compression on PNG and BMP while saving (there's a preview feature so you don't leave tons of files around), but once compression is activated all bets are off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You gotta follow these steps:

1. Multiply height and width (this will help you to know the total number of pixel)
2. Multiply the result by bit depth (this will help you to get the total number of bits data)
3. Divide the result by 8 (then you'll have the file size in bytes)
4. Divide the result of bytes by 1024 (then you'll have the file size in kilobytes)

So your example will be:

1. `(Height * width) = result1`
2. `result1 * bit depth = result2`
3. `result2 / 8 = result3`
4. `result3 / 1024 = finalresult`

Finally we must have:

```
(Height * width * bit depth) / (8 * 1024)
```

If the bit depth is 8, you'll have:

```
(Height * width * 8) / (8 * 1024) = (Height * width)/1024
```